# Android studio Capacitor project Gradle error

Tags: java, android, gradle, splash-screen, capacitor

When i try to open a capacitor [project](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/workflow/) 
( that i m using it to create a splash screen : https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-dynamic-universal-splash-screen-for-capacitor-android/ ) ,
i face a Gradle error :

> Error:Gradle 4.10.1 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently
>   using Java 6.

So i tried to download many java jdk versions but no luck

```
echo $JAVA_HOME returns: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And the SDK (project structure -> SDK location )  is set to :

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

after that i restart many times and no luck ... i need help please !

Build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[android studio gradle error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRyWI.png)

Comment: what's your Android Studio version? Android Studio 2.2 and newer ships with OpenJDK, so you shouldn't need to install or configure the java JDK yourself.

Comment: Android studio 2.1.1 , JRE 1.6 ( about Android studio )

Comment: Can't you update Android Studio? Not sure if that version used the configured JAVA_HOME, but currently you configure the JDK per project in File -> Project Structure